# c# create a method where default parameters do not need to be entered

Tags: c#

I realize this may be a fairly simple question. Still, this is giving me trouble.

I would like to create a method to which a user need only supply one of many parameters. I think the way to do this is to use default parameters. However, in the past, when I have written these, I always run into the following problem:

if I have a method:

```
public void methodName (int a = 1, int b = 2, int c = 3) {
...
}
```

How can somebody who would like to use the method with only parameter c use the method without supplying the defaults for a and b?

I mean obviously if the user calls the method like so:

```
methodName(8)
```

the compiler will understand that a = 8. It seems like the user is forced to supply the parameters even though they are defaults like so:

```
methodName(1, 2, 8)
```

Now, obviously for this simple example I could create a method like so:

```
public void methodName(List<int>) {
}
```

and then the user can only supply the third value in the list.

What do I do if I have many parameters of many types though?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `methodName(c:3)`, explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: @MattBurland Do you mean that when calling it one needs to user methodName([name of parameter in method definition]:[desired value])?

Comment: Yes. When the other unsupplied parameters all have defaults. For example, if your signature was `public void methodName (int a, int b = 2, int c = 3)`, you'd still need to provide `a`, obviously. So you could call `methodName(1,c:3)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for a named argument<sup>1</sup>. To stick with your example, developer would call:

```
methodName(c: 8);
```

<sup>1</sup>: [Named and Optional Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Named and Optional Arguments [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

```
MethodName (c: 8);
```